# Conditional Statements

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, conditional-tags

I have created Custom Post Type called - listing

Also created custom taxonomy - listingcategories

In listing categories, i have created two categories

1. music 2. features

Now i want to create a conditional statement for music category

I am trying this, but its not working

```
<?php global $post;
if (($post->post_type == 'listing') && is_category('music')) { 
//statement
} ?>
```

Am i using it right **is_category()** ?

Please Help.

Thanks
Rajiv

Comment: It seems it should work, but can you also update the code you have used to register the custom post type and the custom taxonomy.

Comment: i used custom post type creator. By which it created default categories

Comment: and where are you using the above set of codes?

Comment: in single-listing.php

Comment: can you update your code with whole code from that file

Comment: listingcategories is a taxonomy, have you tried using $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,"listingcategories",array()); and then checking if terms contains "music" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         <?php if( has_term( 'music', 'listingcategory' ) ) {
                        //content1
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        //content2
                        }
         ?>
```

Got working using this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term

Answer (score 1):

Cheers guy's this helped me a lot, I used the below which works great, any improvements appreciated.

```
    <?php 
          $cat1 = array('category1', 'category2');

           if( has_term( $cat1, 'my_custom_post_type' ) ) {
                  //do something
         } else { //do somthing else}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`is_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) conditional applies to a *specific* taxonomy: **`category`**. The `category` taxonomy, by default, is only registered for the `post` post-type.

You're using a **custom post type** - `listing` - and a **custom taxonomy** - `listingcategories`. As such, you will not be able to use `is_category()` to construct conditional statements for them.

You can use one of the following, depending on your needs:

- [`is_tax( $taxonomy, $term )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax): returns `true` if the current *page* is a *taxonomy archive index*:

  ```
  is_tax( 'listingcategories', 'music' )
  ```
- [`has_term( $taxonomy, $term )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term): returns `true` if the current *post* has the *specified taxonomy term applied*:

  ```
  has_term( 'listingcategories', 'music' )
  ```

So, the analog to your original code would be:

```
<?php global $post;
if ( ($post->post_type == 'listing') && is_tax( 'listingcategories', 'music' ) ) { 
//statement
} ?>
```

And cleaned up using [`get_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type):

```
<?php
if ( 'listingcategories' == get_post_type() && is_tax( 'listingcategories', 'music' ) ) {
    // statement
}
?>
```